# IAm using InetAddress to get server IP but it resolves to local host because my server name is same as server IP, what should I do?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I am using following code to connect Jmeter to a remote mongo DB with authentication. I am using InetAddress to get server IP but it resolves to local host because my server name is same as server IP, what alternative should I use?

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.Arrays;


try {

String mongoUser = vars.get("mongouser");
String userDB = vars.get("userdb");
char[] password = vars.get("password").toCharArray();
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, 
userDB, password);
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new 
ServerAddress(InetAddress.getByName(vars.get("mongohost"))
,vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))}
.build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);

MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName"));
vars.putObject("collection", collection);
return "Connected to " + vars.get("collectionName");
}
catch (Exception e) {
SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Iam getting following error which shows that InetAdress is not resolving my mongo host name (which is same as Mongo host IP i-e 10.80.47.101)

```
Response code: 500
Response message: Exception: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out 
after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is 
{type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=ibexdc1v-dbdev10.corp.ibexglobal.com:27002, 
type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception= 
{com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by 
{java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
```

Comment: rename your local host to something else. or specify exact ip address of mongo server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `ibexdc1v-dbdev10.corp.ibexglobal.com` is correct hostname for your `mongohost` JMeter Variable you check whether MongoDB instances is listening on port `27002` and ensure that the port is open in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
2. If `ibexdc1v-dbdev10.corp.ibexglobal.com` is not correct hostname for your `mongohost` JMeter Variable you should fix your machine [DNS configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)
3. You can explicitly specify the hostname by slightly amending your script, i.e. change this line:

   ```
   builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(InetAddress.getByName(vars.get("mongohost")), vars.get("mongoPort").toInteger())))
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   builder.hosts(Collections.singletonList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongohost"), vars.get("mongoPort") as int)))
   ```

You might also be interested in the [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article